# Avoiding using Cells[x] in a data grid when accessing their values

Tags: c#, datagridview

How do you avoid using dataGrid.Rows[x].Cells[y].Value of a data grid when accessing their values? I want to use descriptive names to refer to cell values, and not indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would be a descriptive name for the *nth* item in `Rows`? I think you're stuck with using a 0-based index since `Rows` doesn't have a string-based indexer.

Once you have a `DataGridViewRow` you can index into the cells using a `string` value:

```
foreach (var row in dataGrid.Rows) {
    var cell = row.Cells["someColumn"];
}
```

Comment: I think rows is okay. What I mean is column. I would like to use any other way to reference the cell value instead of using indices.

Comment: @jasonline How else would you want to get at the values? A positional or associative index is the most natural method.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DataGridView.Rows[index].Cells["CellName"].Value;
```

CellName is your column name.  This works for datagridview.  I don't know about datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

You could put all your data into a class and use data binding. See [How to: Bind Data to the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx) on MSDN.

Then you can access your data fields through your data objects

```
MyDataClass data = (MyDataClass)dataGrid.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
Console.WriteLine(data.LastName);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the datagrid supports indexing with column names, do it like this :

```
dataGrid.Rows[x].Cells["columnName"]
```

I am unsure wether the datagrid supports this syntax, if not, the preferred way I believe would be to use constants to have better code readability like this :

```
const int ColumnNameIndex = 0;
dataGrid.Rows[x].Cells[ColumnNameIndex];
```